# Unable to install perl module in docker file

Tags: docker, perl

I am trying to build a lambda layer with Perl support using this prebuilt docker image: https://metacpan.org/pod/AWS::Lambda#Use-Pre-built-Docker-Images

Now I am trying to add this library libtext-roman-perl into the docker image with:

```
FROM shogo82148/p5-aws-lambda:base-5.36.al2
RUN yum install -y libtext-roman-perl
COPY handler.pl /var/task/
CMD [ "handler.handle" ]
```

but it is showing `No package libtext-roman-perl available.`
Is this because there is no repository containing this libray in the environment?

I've tried yum update but it does not resolve this :(

Comment: Maybe perl packages are not available on amazon linux 2? See also https://serverfault.com/q/643477/201422

Answer (score 3):

`yum install` is Fedora/RedHat/CentOS's way to install packages. These projects use the naming convention `perl-Foo-Bar` for packaging Perl modules. So you could try:

```
RUN yum install -y perl-Text-Roman
```

`libfoo-bar-perl` is the naming convention of Debian/Ubuntu. If you're using one of those distributions (but you don't seem to be), then you'd use `apt` to install it instead of `yum`.

```
RUN apt install libtext-roman-perl
```

Comment: I tried with perl-Text-Roman but seems still cant:
Step 2/4 : RUN yum install -y perl-Text-Roman
 ---> Running in ff207d9f7f51
Loaded plugins: ovl
No package perl-Text-Roman available.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/linux/al2022/release-notes/all-packages-al2022-20230118.html#:~:text=perl-Text-Roman

Comment: ^^^ this link seems to suggest the package *should* exist